# Use non-generic method of Hashset through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, hashset

I want to be able to call the Hashset.ExceptWith() method using reflection but I can't make it happen.

I can't create a generic method. It seems it isn't a generic method.
I also can't seem to call the method itself using invoke.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
var newSet = pi.GetValue(newItem);
var existingSet = pi.GetValue(existingItem);
MethodInfo methodExcept = typeof(HashSet<>).GetMethod("ExceptWith");

//The next line throws: Void ExceptWith(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]) is not a GenericMethodDefinition. 
//MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.'
MethodInfo genericExcept = methodExcept.MakeGenericMethod(pi.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().UnderlyingSystemType);

//The next line throws 'Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.'
methodIntersect.Invoke(existingSet, new[] { newSet });
//The next line is not possible since instantiation of the variable doesn't work
genericIntersect.Invoke(existingSet, new[] { newSet });
```

Comment: The error message says what the problem is.  It's not that you can't make a generic method; it's that you can't call it using a late-bound operation, since the generic type parameter is a compile-time mechanism.

Comment: what is `pi` in the code above? In particular: what does `pi.GetType()` return?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this seems to work. Apparently you have to get the GenericArguments from the Type first.

```
var newSet = pi.GetValue(newItem);
var existingSet = pi.GetValue(existingItem);

var itemsType = existingSet.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

MethodInfo methodExcept = typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(itemsType).GetMethod("ExceptWith");

methodExcept.Invoke(newSet, new[] { existingSet });
```